# Problema en consulta de sql sever

Tags: sql-server

Buen día, tengo una tabla llamada exámenes, en la cual, tengo los campos: Acredita (me muestra 1 si acredito o 0 si no), tengo el campo sede, que es en donde se realizo el examen, así como campo fecha, nivel. Lo que quiero es ver por sede los exámenes aprobados y no aprobados. Lo realice con la siguiente consulta:

```
    SELECT ord.sede, 
       Count(*)                            AS acreditados, 
       (SELECT Count(*) 
        FROM   examenes AS OrdDet 
        WHERE  OrdDet.acredita = 0 
               AND OrdDet.faplica >= '2020-10-01' 
               AND OrdDet.etapaeb = 3 
               AND OrdDet.sede = ord.sede) AS noacreditados 
FROM   examenes AS Ord 
WHERE  Ord.acredita = 1 
       AND Ord.faplica >= '2020-10-01' 
       AND Ord .etapaeb = 3 
GROUP  BY Ord.sede 
ORDER  BY ord.sede;
```

Me arroja lo que necesito, sin embargo, si una sede no tiene aprobados, este registro no me lo muestra aunque tenga exámenes no aprobados.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La cantidad de registros devueltos depende de la consulta principal y ahí se filtran solo los aprobados:

```
WHERE  Ord.acredita = 1
```

Por eso si no hay aprobados ese registro se ignora.

Se puede usar un `CASE` dentro de  `SUM()` para sumar acreditados y no acreditados según el valor de `Ord.acredita` de ese registro y ya no sería necesaria la condición `Ord.acredita = 1` en el `WHERE`:

```
SELECT ord.sede, 
       SUM( CASE WHEN  Ord.acredita = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)  AS acreditados,
       SUM( CASE WHEN  Ord.acredita = 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)  AS nocreditados,   
       
FROM   examenes AS Ord 
WHERE  
       Ord.faplica >= '2020-10-01' 
       AND Ord .etapaeb = 3 
GROUP  BY Ord.sede 
ORDER  BY ord.sede;
```

Comment: Gracias, realice la consulta de esa manera, solo que ahora me atrae el total de acreditados y no acreditados en ambos count

Comment: Es cierto, tenía que ser `SUM()` en lugar de `COUNT()` ya actualicé la respuesta.

Comment: Muchas gracias por el apoyo, en efecto era sum();